# "I am calling to know" VS "I am calling to ask"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-difference

I was going to open a conversation with my doctor over the phone with

> I am calling to know whether my blood test result is ready.

Before doing so, I've read [this topic](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/im-calling-to-know-if-whether-there-is-any-vacancies.2330594/) (on forum.wordreference.com). Now, I am wondering what the difference between these two

> I am calling to **know** whether my blood test result is ready.
>
> I'm calling to **ask** whether my blood test result is ready.

and why the former is completely unnatural and I have to replace it with "ask", but the next might work in a certain context

> **I'd like to know** whether my blood test result is ready.

What is wrong with "know" and why shouldn't I use it to give a reason why I'm calling?

You are welcome to correct the part "my blood test result is ready" if it sounds weird and unnatural to you.

Comment: Both are right (ask and know): It depends on what you want to say. The whether and if thing is a separate issue. The word reference context is about vacancies. That's not the same context at all.